# BASH - Output all Lines between (and including) two identical / almost identical Lines

Tags: bash, aix

So I need to output every line between two almost and possibly identical lines out of a log file.

The log looks something like this:

```
Sat Sep 17 13:03:53
FOOBAR
this is FOO
Sun Sep 18 12:04:12
FOO-1543 Test
FOO-1543 BAR
FOO-1543 Test
FOO-1543 BAR
FOO-1543 Test
Mon Sep 19 00:00:01
FOO-1543 BAR
FOO-1543 Test
Tue Sep 20 16:13:37
FOO-1543 BAR
FOO-1543 Test
```

And so on.

I have already tried using

```
sed -n '/FOO-1543/,/FOO-1543/p' ${input} >> ${output}
sed -n '/^\FOO-1543/,/^\FOO-1543/p' ${input} >> ${output}
awk '/FOO-1543/,/FOO-1543/' ${input} >> ${output}
awk '/^\FOO-1543/,/^\FOO-1543/' ${input} >> ${output}
```

The output I get from these:

```
FOO-1543 Test
FOO-1543 BAR
FOO-1543 Test
FOO-1543 BAR
FOO-1543 Test
FOO-1543 BAR
FOO-1543 Test
FOO-1543 BAR
FOO-1543 Test
```

The output I want:

```
FOO-1543 Test
FOO-1543 BAR
FOO-1543 Test
FOO-1543 BAR
FOO-1543 Test
Mon Sep 19 00:00:01
FOO-1543 BAR
FOO-1543 Test
Tue Sep 20 16:13:37
FOO-1543 BAR
FOO-1543 Test
```

I need to output every line starting from the first FOO-1543 up until the very last time it appears in the document **including lines that don't contain FOO-1543 but are in between the very first and the very last line containing FOO-1543**.

The line number may vary, the beginning of the lines always stays the same.

Please leave an explanation of the solution if possible.

Comment: Umm `grep "^FOO-" input`?

Comment: I don't get what the requirement for what to extract is? What lines is it between?

Comment: Question is not clear at all. Please expand the example to better illustrate what you want.

Comment: edited the Question, hope it is more clear what i need now

Comment: `sed -n '/FOO-1543/,/FOO-1543/p'` matches the expected output on GNU sed 4.2.2, may be your sed version is different and hence didn't give expected results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print all lines in between the first and last occurrence of `FOO-`, you can use the following:

```
awk '/^FOO-/{if(!b)b=NR;e=NR} {a[NR]=$0} END{for(i=b;i<=e;i++) print a[i]}' file
```

This is setting the start line with index `b` and the end line with `e`.

The whole file is duped into an array `a`.

The wanted lines are printed based on the 2 indexes `b` and `e` in the `END` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If `perl` solution is okay:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /^FOO-1543/.../^FOO-1543/' ip.txt 
FOO-1543 Test
FOO-1543 BAR
FOO-1543 Test
FOO-1543 BAR
FOO-1543 Test
Mon Sep 19 00:00:01
FOO-1543 BAR
FOO-1543 Test
Tue Sep 20 16:13:37
FOO-1543 BAR
FOO-1543 Test
```

The `...` version of [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) is needed in this case

`sed -n '/^FOO-1543/,/^FOO-1543/p' ip.txt` works as well for me on `GNU sed 4.2.2`